# Composition of relations of an image. Prove: $(\rho_2\circ\rho_1)(A)=\rho_2(\rho_1(A))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\rho_1\subseteq S_1\times S_2$ and $\rho_2\subseteq S_2\times S_3$ are some arbitrary binary relations and $A\subseteq S_1$ some set, then $(\rho_2\circ\rho_1)(A)=\rho_2(\rho_1(A))$. How to prove this?

I know that $$(\rho_2\circ\rho_1)(A)=\{c\in S_3:(a,c)\in(\rho_2\circ\rho_1) \text{ for some }a\in A\}=\{c\in S_3:((a,b)\in \rho_1\land (b,c)\in \rho_2)\text{ for some }a\in A\}$$
but how to continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a, c) \in (\rho_2 \circ \rho_1)(A)$. By the definition of composition, there exists $b \in S_2$ such that $(a, b) \in \rho_1$ and $(b, c) \in \rho_2$.

Since $(a, b) \in \rho_1$ and $b \in \rho_1(A)$, we have $a \in S_1$ and $b \in \rho_1(A)$. Also, $(b, c) \in \rho_2$, so $c \in \rho_2(b)$.

Therefore, $(a, c) \in \rho_2(\rho_1(A))$, which implies $(\rho_2 \circ \rho_1)(A) \subseteq \rho_2(\rho_1(A))$.
Let $c \in \rho_2(\rho_1(A))$. By the definition of $\rho_2(\rho_1(A))$, there exists $b \in S_2$ such that $b \in \rho_1(A)$ and $(b, c) \in \rho_2$.

Since $b \in \rho_1(A)$, there exists $a \in S_1$ such that $(a, b) \in \rho_1$.

Therefore, $(a, c) \in (\rho_2 \circ \rho_1)(A)$ because $(a, b) \in \rho_1$ and $(b, c) \in \rho_2$, which implies $\rho_2(\rho_1(A)) \subseteq (\rho_2 \circ \rho_1)(A)$.

Combining both proofs, we have $(\rho_2 \circ \rho_1)(A) = \rho_2(\rho_1(A))$, which completes the proof.